# Ruby on Rails Export CSV data to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented CSV export, and now I am trying to export data to PDF.

How can one export the CSV data from the CSV generated file to PDF.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use prawn https://github.com/sandal/prawn to generate pdfs in ruby with some code like:

```
require 'prawn'
pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text(my_csv_data)
pdf.render_file('csv.pdf')
```

There is also a tutorial here: http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/10/13/how-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-with-prawn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFKit
Try these link s:

http://rubygems.org/gems/pdfkit

https://github.com/grosser/PDFKit/